# Getting white screen second time after present the vc on top of current vc. Not getting it for first time

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to show my session vc after i get values (i am using notification center) from my non UIViewController class (my interface class which is from my cocoa class) to my session vc.

Now for the first time, my session vc is showing correctly on my current top vc. But after second time, i am getting only white screen. But the values, api calls which is having in my session vc is still running.I can see in my console.

**TopView.swift :**

```
import UIKit

public extension UIWindow {
    public var visibleViewController: UIViewController? {
        return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc: self.rootViewController)
    }

    public static func getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nc = vc as? UINavigationController {
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc: nc.visibleViewController)
        } else if let tc = vc as? UITabBarController {
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc: tc.selectedViewController)
        } else {
            if let pvc = vc?.presentedViewController {
                return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc: pvc)
            } else {
                return vc
            }
        }
    }
}

func getTopViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
    if let window = appDelegate!.window {
        return window?.visibleViewController
    }
    return nil
}
```

My app delegate :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.onOver(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "openBoard"), object: nil);


}

@objc func onGameOver(notification: NSNotification)
    {
   if let score = notification.object as? NSDictionary
        {


                    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Trai", bundle: nil);
                    if let sessionvc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
                        "sessionvc") as? sessionvc{


                        if let topVC = getTopViewController() {
                            //topVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                            topVC.present(sessionvc, animated: true)
                        }

                }

        }
    }
```

For first time i am not getting it. But from second time if i try to do same i am getting white screen but still my sessionvc data and all loading in my console. Any help on this

Comment: the code is correct. But check wether your topVC top vc is same like first time . If your topVC is getting changed.Then you needs to call your nonviewcontroller class everytime. Assign it to rootvc and then proceed.It will work.

Comment: Yes, can u please help m on that

Answer (score 0):

May be its an late replay. Let me know if its helps you.

Change your method `@objc func onGameOver(notification: NSNotification)`

```
if let topVC = getTopViewController() {

  let Yourvc = YourViewController()
  topVC = Yourvc
  topVC.present(topVC, animated: true)

 }
```

Else you can try out this method :

```
if var topVC = getTopViewController() {

  self.window?.rootViewController = topVC
  topVC.present(scoreBoardController, animated: true)

}
```

Try and let me know if its works.

Comment: Can you please help me on this issues - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56673171/getting-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value-i

Comment: I will check your above solution , thanks for your help